# Added middleware doesnt get invoked on page load in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

I've created custom middleware elements that I add in Configure, but they never get invoked.

Do I add them wrong or at the wrong place?
I want them to run on every page load.

**Configure**:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAssetsSites(this IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration configuration, params IAppFeatureBase[] features)
{
    CookiePolicyOptions cookie = new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        CheckConsentNeeded = context => true,
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None
    };

    app
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseSession()
        .UseCookiePolicy(cookie);

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.DefaultRoute))
    {
        DefaultRoute route = (DefaultRoute)features.Single(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.DefaultRoute);

        app.UseEndpoints(opt => {
            opt.MapControllerRoute("default", route.Route);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.Localization))
    {
        Localization local = (Localization)features.Single(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.Localization);

        app
            .UseRequestLocalization(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultRequestCulture = local.DefaultCulture;
                opt.SupportedCultures = local.SupportedCultures.ToList();
                opt.SupportedUICultures = local.SupportedCultures.ToList();
            })
            .UseMiddleware<CultureRedirect>(configuration)
            .UseMiddleware<SetCultureFromQuery>();
    }

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.SSL))
    {
        app
            .UseHttpsRedirection();
    }

    return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation of the recommended configuring order when adding middleware.
Adding them higher in the pipeline worked.

**Code**:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAssetsSites(this IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration configuration, params IAppFeatureBase[] features)
{
    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.SSL))
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }

    app
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseCookiePolicy()
        .UseRouting();

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.Localization))
    {
        Localization local = (Localization)features.Single(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.Localization);

        app
            .UseMiddleware<CultureRedirect>(configuration)
            .UseMiddleware<SetCultureFromQuery>()
            .UseRequestLocalization(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultRequestCulture = local.DefaultCulture;
                opt.SupportedCultures = local.SupportedCultures.ToList();
                opt.SupportedUICultures = local.SupportedCultures.ToList();
            });
    }

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.Identity))
    {
        app
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseAuthorization();
    }

    app.UseSession();

    if (features.Exists(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.DefaultRoute))
    {
        DefaultRoute route = (DefaultRoute)features.Single(feat => feat.Type == AppFeatures.DefaultRoute);

        app.UseEndpoints(opt =>
        {
            opt.MapControllerRoute("default", route.Route);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }

    return app;
}
```